# how show 'object' variable in inspector unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inspector

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Column
{
    public string Name;

    public List<object> Attribute;
}
```

I cant see

> Attribute

in inspector.

And if use

```
public List<object> Attribute= new List<object>();
```

All values will be lost.

And if not used I'm receive an Null error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to make `object` serializable, but I suggest you create a serializable struct/class and use that one for the List like `List<YourSerializableObject>`.

In addition to that, you may want to look into [PropertyDrawer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PropertyDrawer.html)